# Parsing Nested Array String

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to parse an arbitrarily nested array in a String, in this format: `[3,[4,3],5]`, to a List(of lists, of lists...)

My example, once parsed, would be a list that looks something like this:

```
List(3, List(4, 3), 5)
```

I wrote some code (in the previous edits of this question), but none of my drafts worked. Could I have either a sample implementation or some pseudo-code?

Comment: It's kind of funny that my code uses a stack, has a StackOverflowException, and I posted it on StackOverflow.com

Comment: what is expected outcome here? If I know, I may post some ideas later

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57796/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-kyranstar).

Comment: BTW, that input is JSON.  There are ready-made JSON parsers that will parse into a List containing another List just as you suggest.  See json.org.

Comment: Here's what I built with the help of @i_turo's answer, although in C++, which works with more-than-one-character entries: http://pastebin.com/kP7prEcd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parsing a nested-array to such a String is rather simple:

```
Arrays.deepToString(array).replace(" ", "");
```

Converting this String to an infinitely nested-list is a bit more tricky. The easiest solution would probably be to use recursion:

```
/**
 * The following code is only for demonstration purposes.
 * It does neither do any validation on the input String 
 * nor work with more than one digit numbers.
 */

static int index = 0; // the position in the String

Object buildList(String nestedList) {
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

    while (index < nestedList.length()) {
        char c = nestedList.charAt(index++);

        if (c == '[') // add a sub-list via a recursive call
                list.add(buildList(nestedList));
        else if (c == ']') // stop building the list
                 break;
        else if (c == ',') {} // do nothing
        else // add an element to the list
            list.add(c);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Example call:

```
System.out.println(buildList("[3,[4,3],5]")); // prints [3, [4, 3], 5]
```

**Note:**

Even though the above code does what (at least I think) you want to achieve, it may not be advisable to use such a data-structure in practice, since the access to the nested-lists is quite complicated and involves some casting.

A better solution would probably be to use some kind of tree-datastructure where each node has a list of values including links to other nodes. 
(see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure))

Comment: Possible improvements: Use Java8 OfInt via `"[1,2]".chars().iterator().nextInt()`, and use switch/case statement. Also Instead of returning a List<Object>, better to pass some Observer into the method.